# Question: Single Spa with an Angular Parcel with dynamic routing inside the Parcel

Tags: angular-routing, angular-router, single-spa, dynamic-routing, single-spa-angular

**Describe the bug or question**

I am creating a micro frontend using Single Spa.
The parcel is in angular.
The parcel contains 2 components: The Payment component and the success component.

My question is how can I dynamically navigate through several components within the same parcel using single spa.
I have been looking for examples but in none of them I have found an internal navigation inside the parcel using angular.
I don't know if that is possible either, because I was looking at documentation about routing in single-spa with Angular and the registerApplication and the Module Federation but neither.

**To Reproduce**

I have created 2 repositories, **the first one** with only the angular project running.
https://github.com/AlvaroGuGo303/AngularDemo1

> Execute
>
> `npm start`
>
> Navigate to `http://localhost:4400/`. The application will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.

And the **second one**, where single spa is implemented and the angular project is as a parcel.
https://github.com/AlvaroGuGo303/AngularSingleSpaDemo2

> Execute
>
> `npm start`
>
> Open another terminal and execute:
>
> `cd parcel1Angular/demo`
>
> `npm start`
>
> Navigate to `http://localhost:9000/`. The application will automatically reload if you change any of the source files.

The problem I would say is in the
`microfrontend-layout.html`
in the section of the `<single-spa-router>`
when defining the routes, which is unable to do it, Because if instead of putting
`<route path="parcel1">`
you put
`<route default>`
then it works.
But the problem then is that if you want to add more parcels, how do you do to not display them all at once.

**Expected behavior**

The expected behavior is to be able to navigate within the angular parcel using single spa as the AngularDemo1 project does independently.

**Screenshots and/or console output**

(My profile is not able to show screenshots but you can see on:
https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa/issues/1114)

**Single-Spa-Root-Container**

*microfrontend-layout.html*

```
<single-spa-router>
  <main>
    <route path="parcel1">
      <application name="@microfrontend/parcel1Angular"></application>
    </route>
  </main>
</single-spa-router>
```

*index.ejs*

```
.....
  <% if (isLocal) { %>
  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@microfrontend/root-config": "http://localhost:9000/microfrontend-root-config.js",
        "@microfrontend/parcel1Angular": "http://localhost:4200/main.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <% } %>
.....
```

*microfrontend-root-config.ts*

```
import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";
import {
  constructApplications,
  constructRoutes,
  constructLayoutEngine,
} from "single-spa-layout";
import microfrontendLayout from "./microfrontend-layout.html";

const routes = constructRoutes(microfrontendLayout);
const applications = constructApplications({
  routes,
  loadApp({ name }) {
    return System.import(name);
  },
});
const layoutEngine = constructLayoutEngine({ routes, applications });

applications.forEach(registerApplication);
layoutEngine.activate();
start();
```

**Single-Spa-Angular-Parcel**

*index.html*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <base href="/parcel1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-b-root></app-b-root>
</body>
</html>
```

*app-component.html* (the one with selector app-b-root)

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*nav.component.html*

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a aria-current="page" routerLink="/">Payment</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a routerLink="/success">Success</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {PaymentComponent} from "./payment/payment.component";
import {SuccessComponent} from "./success/success.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PaymentComponent },
  { path: 'success', component: SuccessComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Additional context**

Single Spa with an Angular Parcel with dynamic routing inside the Parcel

Comment: Hello.  I quickly read the beginning of your question.  First of all, I think you have a single-spa application, not a parcel.  Parcels are "foreign" UI pieces imported from one mife into another.  This does not seem to fit what you describe.  Second, single-spa by default has no routing.  It only listens to routing events.  As long as the internal routing causes a truthy value of of the application's activity function, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Just fix on github.
Need: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#configure-routes

See last commit on https://github.com/AlvaroGuGo303/AngularSingleSpaDemo2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).